# Rails 3. How to remove duplicate associated records from query result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have @invoices, which contains all invoices related to a particular scheduled course.

```
scheduled_course has_many :invoices, through => :enrollments
invoices belongs_to :scheduled_courses

@scheduled_course = ScheduledCourse.find(params[:id])
@invoices = @scheduled_course.invoices
```

Now, some invoices might be duplicated. For example, `@invoices - @scheduled_course.invoices` might output...

```
=> [#<Invoice id: 85, company_id: 106, invoice_number: "2870", issued_on: "2012-03-27", status: "pagado", notes: "", created_at: "2012-05-02 15:28:13", updated_at: "2012-05-02 15:50:50", exchange_rate: #<BigDecimal:c2bcc9c,'0.12E2',4(8)>, student_id: nil, due_date: "2012-04-02">, 
#<Invoice id: 85, company_id: 106, invoice_number: "2870", issued_on: "2012-03-27", status: "pagado", notes: "", created_at: "2012-05-02 15:28:13", updated_at: "2012-05-02 15:50:50", exchange_rate: #<BigDecimal:c2b828c,'0.12E2',4(8)>, student_id: nil, due_date: "2012-04-02">, 
#<Invoice id: 85, company_id: 106, invoice_number: "2870", issued_on: "2012-03-27", status: "pagado", notes: "", created_at: "2012-05-02 15:28:13", updated_at: "2012-05-02 15:50:50", exchange_rate: #<BigDecimal:c2b7e54,'0.12E2',4(8)>, student_id: nil, due_date: "2012-04-02">, 
#<Invoice id: 85, company_id: 106, invoice_number: "2870", issued_on: "2012-03-27", status: "pagado", notes: "", created_at: "2012-05-02 15:28:13", updated_at: "2012-05-02 15:50:50", exchange_rate: #<BigDecimal:c2b7a1c,'0.12E2',4(8)>, student_id: nil, due_date: "2012-04-02">, 
#<Invoice id: 85, company_id: 106, invoice_number: "2870", issued_on: "2012-03-27", status: "pagado", notes: "", created_at: "2012-05-02 15:28:13", updated_at: "2012-05-02 15:50:50", exchange_rate: #<BigDecimal:c2b75e4,'0.12E2',4(8)>, student_id: nil, due_date: "2012-04-02">, #<Invoice id: 85, company_id: 106, invoice_number: "2870", issued_on: "2012-03-27", status: "pagado", notes: "", created_at: "2012-05-02 15:28:13", updated_at: "2012-05-02 15:50:50", exchange_rate: #<BigDecimal:c2b7198,'0.12E2',4(8)>, student_id: nil, due_date: "2012-04-02">
```

How can I remove duplicated objects from the result?

Comment: Can't you just call uniq on it?

Comment: Using uniq will convert the query into an array, which may have negative impact on performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the `:uniq` option to has many:

```
has_many :invoices, :through => :enrollments, :uniq => true
```

Here's the description from the RoR docs for this option:

> If true, duplicates will be omitted from the collection. Useful in conjunction with :through.

Also, to avoid duplicates from entering the DB in the first place, you may be able to use a unique DB index, which may look something like this:

```
add_index :enrollments, [:invoice_id, :scheduled_course_id], :unique => true
```

Comment: This solution will be deprecated in Rails 4.0, and maybe even not present in Rails 4.1, so the alternative lambda version is encouraged: has_many :invoices, -> { # get unique elements }, :through => :enrollments

Answer (score 3):

```
@scheduled_course.invoices.uniq(&:id) # uniq elements in the array by their id
```

Just using `@scheduled_course.invoices.uniq` should also work.

Comment: Bear in mind that #uniq will convert the ActiveRecord association into an array of invoices, which can have a negative impact on the performance and time needed to get the elements.

Comment: Yes, use `distinct` instead.